# bash - sum numbers in a variable

Tags: bash, variable, arithmetic, bc

I have a variable set with numbers separated with space, of which first number can also be led by space, example:

```
VAR=" 2 1  34 3    2 "
```

I need to sum all these numbers. Easiest way would be replacing all spaces in between numbers with `+` and pipe on bc

I can do it with a for loop, paste and bc, but maybe someone knows easier way to do it? Maybe some calculation directly in bash on a `VAR` with bash built-in string replacements?

```
$ for i in $VAR;do echo $i;done|paste -sd+|bc
42
```

update: Thx for all proposal, I finally found quite short method with an array:

```
$ VAR=" 2 1  34 3    2 "
$ arr=( $VAR );echo "$((${arr[@]/%/+}0))"
42
$ VAR="$VAR -14"
$ arr=( $VAR );echo "$((${arr[@]/%/+}0))"
28
$
```

Comment: Please not that this will only work for integers.  If you need to add float-values, pipe to bc.  `echo "${arr[@]/%/+}0" | bc`

Answer (score 7):

Your source string has repeated spaces and leading/trailing spaces.

A naive conversion of spaces to `+` will fail:

```
$ value='      2 1  34 3    2    '
$ echo "${value// /+}"
++++++2+1++34+3++++2++++
```

To colapse all repeated spaces **and** remove leading/trailing space you just need an echo (or printf) for an unquoted variable (assuming IFS is default):

```
value=$(echo $value)
echo "${value// /+}"
2+1+34+3+2
```

And that could be feed to bc:

```
$ echo "${value// /+}" | bc
42
```

All in one line, if you want that:

`value=$(echo $value); echo "${value// /+}" | bc`

Or, even using `sed` as a filter (no aditional variable, but slower):

`echo $value | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc`

A previous attempt at this with `<<<` had a problem:

```
$ ~/bin/b44sh -c 'value="      2 1  34 3    2    ";sed "s/ /+/g" <<<$value'
++++++2+1++34+3++++2++++
```

On bash since version 4.4. On previous versions it worked as this:

```
~/bin/b43sh -c 'value="      2 1  34 3    2    ";sed "s/ /+/g" <<<$value'
2+1+34+3+2
```

For any version of bash (and sed) we can do (a quite robust version but calls an external utility -`sed`):

```
sed "s/ \+/+/g" <<<"0 $value 0"     | tee /dev/tty     | bc
0+2+1+34+3+2+0
42
```

---

A pure shell solution (demands bash,ksh or zsh for the replacement `${//}` part)could be:

`value=$(echo $value); bc <<<"${value// /+}`

And a more **robust** (enforce your assumptions™) and **portable** version:

- avoid that changes of IFS affect the present shell. Use a sub shell `(…)`.
- ensure that IFS breaks values on spaces (IFS=" ")
- ensure that even if unquoted, the string will not expand `*` et all (set -f).
- ensure that parts are joined with a `+` (IFS=+).

`( IFS=" "; set -f; set -- $value; IFS=+; echo "$*" | bc; )`

A function version
 1- if your shell doesn't allow `local`, use the slower sub-shell form
 2- Some (correctly in POSIX) may complain about using an unquoted `$*`.

`sum(){ local IFS=" "; set -f; set -- $*; IFS=+; echo "$*" | bc; }`

Which adds arguments in many ways

```
$ value="      2 1  34 3    2    "
$ sum "$value"
42
$ sum $value    # beware of glob chars *, ? and [  and of odd IFS=123 settings
42
$ sum "      2 1  34 3    2    "
42
$ sum "      2"    "1  "    "34 3"    "    2    "
42
$ var=23
$ sum "      2"    "1  "    "34 3"    "    2    "   "$var"
65
```

Answer (score 4):

Use parameter expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=" 2 1  34 3    2 "

shopt -s extglob                # Enable the `+(...)` construct.
expression=${VAR#+(\ )}         # Remove leading spaces.
expression=${expression%+(\ )}  # Remove trailing spaces.
bc <<< ${expression//+(\ )/+}   # Replace strings of spaces by pluses.
```

Comment: Bash replacement is extremely slow, don't use it. Make the variable `expression=$(printf "%.0sword   " {1..100})` (just 100 words) and test: `shopt -s extglob; time echo "${expression//+(\ )/+}"`

Answer (score 4):

A few Perl tricks:

```
$ perl -lane '$t+=$_ for @F; print $t' <<<"$var"
42
```

Or

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d)\s+(?=\d)/$1+/g' <<<"$var" | bc
42
```

Or

```
$ perl -lane 'print eval join "+", @F' <<<"$var"
42
```

Or GNU `sed` and coreutils:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '+' <<<$var | sed 's/^+//; s/+$//' | bc
42
```

Comment: Another one (relies on word splitting... not sure if this should be encouraged) `printf '%d+' $VAR | dc -e0 -f- -ep`

Comment: @steeldriver oooh, nice! Sure, it's probably illegal in multiple territories, but it's still simple, elegant and works in this example. I'd post it!

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Chris' array solution:

```
$ var=" 2 1  34 3    2 "
$ var=$(echo $var); echo "$((${var// /+}))"
42
```

Trim and squeeze all space characters, then replace all space characters with `+` and evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

bash scripts:

```
$ v="2 4 7 10 3"
$ s=0
$ for i in $v
> do
> s=$((s+i))
> done
$ echo $s
26
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of the variable you can use awk like this :

```
echo $VAR | awk '{print $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 + $5}'
```

Output:

```
42
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Doing it in a loop from 1 to `NF` would make it a generic solution for an unknown number of numbers.

Comment: Or add records instead of fields: `echo "$VAR" | awk '{a+=$0}END{print a}' RS=' '`

Comment: Or simply `awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sum += $i;print sum}' <<<$VAR`

Comment: Dear Shmuel - sana tova

Comment: Thanks @yael you too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the constituent numbers are integers, this should work too (this is due to `declare` or `typeset` accepting an arithmetic expression to initialize an integer variable)

```
VAR=" 2 1  34 3    2 "
read -r VAR <<<$VAR #shed leading and trailing spaces, compact internal spaces
VAR=${VAR// /+}   #replace spaces with plusses
declare -i var=$VAR     #typeset var to an integer
echo $var
42
```